# What ping options should I specify in Linux to mimic Windows defaults?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ping, default-settings

If you've ever run `ping` on both a Windows PC and a Linux PC it becomes rather apparent they don't use the same settings such as packet size, TTL, wait time, etc. What `ping` options should I specify in Linux so that I'm using the same settings as a Windows PC (with default options)?

What I've gathered so far by comparing the [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping) to the [Arch Linux manpage](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/ping.8).

```
ping -c 4 -s 32 -M dont -t ?? -Q 0 -W 4 www.google.com
```

1. **`-c 4`**  Send a total of 4 packets (Windows default). Linux default is ∞.
2. **`-s 32`**  Use 32 bytes of data (Windows default). Linux default is 56. *Note that this does not include the 28 bytes ICMP and ECHO_REQUEST headers.*
3. **`-M dont`** Do not set DF (packet fragmentation) flag. Microsoft Docs seem to imply fragmentation is allowed, manpage doesn't state the default.
4. **`-t ??`** Set TTL (time-to-live). Microsoft Docs state *"The default is the default TTL value for the host."* Manpage doesn't indicate a default value.

   - **How do I determine the default host TTL?**
5. **`-Q 0`** I believe the equivalent Windows option is `/v <TOS>`  which states the default is `0`.
6. **`-W 4`** Wait timeout / time to wait for a response. Microsfot Docs state the default is 4 seconds.

Comment: Is there a reason why one should try to mimic Windows' ping defaults? What is the benefit of doing so?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen, Was comparing the results from different networks of pinging Google. It would be easier to compare if the settings were the same. One network only has Windows PC's, the other only has Linux PCs.

Comment: Okey. I understand that it would be easier to compare them. Obviously I don't know the answer to your question, but reason I asked you those questions was that it might be hard or impossible to make ping behave exactly the same. Have you inspected that the ICMP packets are the same on both implementations?